# How to make color the wick portion of a candlestick stick using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm looking to make the wick portion of a candlestick stick black using matplotlib? I couldn't find any mention of it in the documentation, but I've seen pictoral examples showing that it can be done.

here's what I currently have:

[image]

here's an example of the wicks being colored black:

[image]

Update:

I used the solution provided below but changed the code slightly to remove the vertical line over the body area of the candlestick:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


def blackwickcandlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='#00FF00', colordown='#FF0000',
                         alpha=1.0, shadowCol='k', ochl=True):

    OFFSET = width / 2.0

    lines = []
    patches = []
    for q in quotes:
        if ochl:
            t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]
        else:
            t, open, high, low, close = q[:5]

        if close >= open:
            color = colorup
            lower = open
            height = close - open
            vline = Line2D(
                xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
                color=colorup,      # This changed from the default implementation
                linewidth=0.5,
                antialiased=True,
                )
        else:
            color = colordown
            lower = close
            height = open - close
            vline = Line2D(
                xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
                color=colordown,      # This changed from the default implementation
                linewidth=0.5,
                antialiased=True,
                )


        rect = Rectangle(
            xy=(t - OFFSET, lower),
            width=width,
            height=height,
            facecolor=color,
            edgecolor=color,
        )
        rect.set_alpha(alpha)

        lines.append(vline)
        patches.append(rect)
        ax.add_line(vline)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    return lines, patches


import matplotlib.finance as mpl_finance

mpl_finance._candlestick = blackwickcandlestick
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul says, A MCVE would assist people in helping you greatly.

However - just having a quick glance at the source code for the candlestick plotting in matplotlib shows that it uses the colorup/colordown parameter for both the candle and the wick.

So in order to get them to be different colours you will most likely need to reimplement the method and/or monkey patch the base implementation.

So in your plotting module, use something along the lines of:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


def blackwickcandlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='k', colordown='r',
                         alpha=1.0, ochl=True):

    OFFSET = width / 2.0

    lines = []
    patches = []
    for q in quotes:
        if ochl:
            t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]
        else:
            t, open, high, low, close = q[:5]

        if close >= open:
            color = colorup
            lower = open
            height = close - open
        else:
            color = colordown
            lower = close
            height = open - close

        vline = Line2D(
            xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
            color='k',      # This is the only line changed from the default implmentation
            linewidth=0.5,
            antialiased=True,
        )

        rect = Rectangle(
            xy=(t - OFFSET, lower),
            width=width,
            height=height,
            facecolor=color,
            edgecolor=color,
        )
        rect.set_alpha(alpha)

        lines.append(vline)
        patches.append(rect)
        ax.add_line(vline)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    return lines, patches


import matplotlib.finance as mpl_finance

mpl_finance._candlestick = blackwickcandlestick
```

Then elsewhere in this module you can use the `mpl_finance.candlestick_ohlc(...)` plotting functions.

Answer (score 5):

Rewriting the complete `candlestick_ohlc` seems overly complicated. You can just iterate over the lines returned by the function and set their color to black. You may also set the `zorder` to have the wicks appear below the boxes.

```
lines, patches = candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.5)
for line, patch in zip(lines, patches):
    patch.set_edgecolor("k")
    patch.set_linewidth(0.72)
    patch.set_antialiased(False)
    line.set_color("k")
    line.set_zorder(0)
```

[image]

If this is to be used often in a script, you can of course put it in a function.

```
def candlestick_ohlc_black(*args,**kwargs):
    lines, patches = candlestick_ohlc(*args,**kwargs)
    for line, patch in zip(lines, patches):
        patch.set_edgecolor("k")
        patch.set_linewidth(0.72)
        patch.set_antialiased(False)
        line.set_color("k")
        line.set_zorder(0)

candlestick_ohlc_black(ax, quotes, width=0.5)
```

Comment: Yeah, - a much better approach than mine and of course easier to extend to whatever colour border/line you like.