# Candlestick plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I plot a candlestick chart with python 3 using matplotlib. There is one thing that looks not as I would like. It's lines in candles body (see the image below). Thus the question:

Is there a way to avoid their presence? Also, I need to keep the black/white style.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As seen e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43249954/4124317), you can obtain the lines and patches of the candlestick graph and change their properties to your likings:

```
lines, patches = candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.5)
for line, patch in zip(lines, patches):
    patch.set_edgecolor("k")
    patch.set_linewidth(0.72)
    patch.set_antialiased(False)
    line.set_color("k")
    line.set_zorder(0) # make lines appear behind the patches
    line.set_visible(False) # make them invisible
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what I've asked! But the last line deletes all of the shadows, thus it should be removed.

Comment: All of those those are some options you have. You may choose which ones to use for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I developed [finplot](https://pypi.org/project/finplot/), to get a better API and higher performance. finplot does not have this rendering bug on hollow candles by default.

```
import finplot as fplt
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download('AAPL', '2020-05-01')

ax,axv = fplt.create_plot('Apple Inc.', rows=2)
cplot = fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open','Close','High','Low']], ax=ax)
vplot = fplt.volume_ocv(df[['Open','Close','Volume']], ax=axv)

cplot.colors.update(dict(bull_frame='#000', bull_body='#fff', bull_shadow='#000', bear_frame='#000', bear_body='#000', bear_shadow='#000'))
vplot.colors.update(dict(bull_frame='#000', bull_body='#fff', bear_frame='#000', bear_body='#000'))

fplt.show()
```

[image: finplot b/w]

Comment: I used finplot for candles form binance. I loaded candles from csv file, next i tried to plot those candles. The problem is that all candles are looking like growing candles. I do not have right one colors. I thing i pass columns in the correct order   candles = df[['time','open','close','high','low']]. Howewer when  i try code https://pypi.org/project/finplot/ from example 2, all is working fine. Have you advice for me?

Comment: @luki Post an example of your problem including data in the [discussions](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/discussions) and I'll have a look.

Comment: @ Jonas. I paste my code and info about data there: https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/discussions/277