# Problem customizing wicks and candlesticks in matplotlib (mpl_finance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, charts, candlestick-chart

I was looking to implement the code from the user: [importanceofbeingernest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)

In the following post: 
[How to make color the wick portion of a candlestick stick using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240157/how-to-make-color-the-wick-portion-of-a-candlestick-stick-using-matplotlib)

However, when I tried to implement it using `candlestick2_ohlc` gave the following error:

```
    141 
--> 142   for line, patch in zip(lines, patches):
    143       patch.set_edgecolor("k")
    144       patch.set_linewidth(0.72)

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Here's the **code**:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  candlestick2_ohlc(ax,quotes['Open'],quotes['High'],quotes['Low'],quotes['Close'],width=0.5)

  lines, patches = candlestick2_ohlc(ax,quotes['Open'],quotes['High'],quotes['Low'],quotes['Close'],width=0.5)

  for line, patch in zip(lines, patches):
      patch.set_edgecolor("k")
      patch.set_linewidth(0.72)
      patch.set_antialiased(False)
      line.set_color("k")
      line.set_zorder(0)

  candlestick_ohlc_black(ax,quotes['Open'],quotes['High'],quotes['Low'],quotes['Close'],width=0.5)
```

This is from **matplotlib doc**. Notice by using the **candlestick2_ohlc** method I must add opens, high, lows, closes as parameters, instead of them all stacked.

```
matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, lows, closes, width=4, colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75)
```

**I also tried** this instead of the `for line, patch in zip(lines, patches):` loop:

```
for line in lines: 
    line.set_color("k")
    line.set_zorder(0)

  for patch in patches:
    patch.set_edgecolor("k")
    patch.set_linewidth(0.72)
    patch.set_antialiased(False)
```

And got the following **error**:

```
    141 
--> 142   for line in lines:
    143     line.set_color("k")
    144     line.set_zorder(0)

TypeError: 'LineCollection' object is not iterable
```

UPDATE, thanks to [importanceofbeingernest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest), I also tried:

```
  lines, patches = candlestick2_ohlc(ax,quotes['Open'],quotes['High'],quotes['Low'],quotes['Close'],width=0.5,colorup='g',colordown='r')

  patches.set_edgecolor("k") # works
  patches.set_linewidth(0.72) #works
  patches.set_antialiased(False) # no idea if works
  lines.set_color("b") # doesn't work
  lines.set_zorder(0) #doesn't work
```

Lines can't seem to work but patches do.
Still trying to find a way to work it out.

**UPDATE 2 minimal sample code that shows a chart:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc 

def generate_chart_EnterTrade(quotes):
  quotes['Date'] = quotes.index
  # Order the dataframe
  quotes = quotes[['Date','Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close','Volume']] 

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  candlestick2_ohlc(ax,quotes['Open'],quotes['High'],quotes['Low'],quotes['Close'],width=0.33,colorup='g',colordown='r')
  '''
  lines, patches = candlestick2_ohlc(ax,quotes['Open'],quotes['High'],quotes['Low'],quotes['Close'],width=0.5,colorup='g',colordown='r')

  patches.set_edgecolor("k") # works
  patches.set_linewidth(0.72) #works
  patches.set_antialiased(False) # no idea if works
  lines.set_color("b") # doesn't work
  lines.set_zorder(0) #doesn't work
  '''

  def mydate(x,pos):
      try: 
          a = quotes['Date'][int(x)]
          return '{: %d %b}'.format(a)
      except IndexError:
          return ''


  ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mydate))

  ax.yaxis.tick_right()
  fig.tight_layout()   
  plt.grid(color='#C0C0C0', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
  plt.show()


end = datetime.datetime.now()
start = end - datetime.timedelta(days=100)
data = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)

generate_chart_EnterTrade(data)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I suppose the presented method in the linked answer only works for `candlestick_*`, not for `candlestick2_*` functions.

Comment: Any idea about how to work it out?... I am using `candlestick2_` because it removes the date gap `candlestick_` has during weekends on the x axis @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: For most parameters it should be possible to directly manipulate the linecollection, `lines, patches = candlestick2_ohlc(...); lines.set_color("k")` etc.

Comment: I updated the question with the code I have tried, patches do work by doing that but lines don't. I have been searching in google about `LineCollection` and nothing

Comment: Ok, if you can provide a minimal example code that I can copy and paste as is, I can look further into it.

Comment: Updated the question and included the code with the output you should get. It's at the bottom of the question under **UPDATE 2**, the code should work I just tried it in a jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me

```
lines, patches = candlestick2_ohlc(ax, ..., alpha=1)
lines.set_color("b")
lines.set_zorder(1)
```

and results in this plot (zoomed in):

[image]